# How can eclipse find 'javax.servlet' when using the gradle with plugins 'war' and 'jetty'

Tags: eclipse, servlets, gradle, jetty, war

This must be very basic. But I just don't know how to make it work.

I'm following the book "Gradle in Action".  When making the webapp the following is put in the `build.gradle` file

```
dependencies {
    providedCompile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5',
            'javax.servlet.jsp:jsp-api:2.1'
    runtime 'javax.servlet:jstl:1.1.2',
            'taglibs:standard:1.1.2'
}
```

I'm using eclipse.  But it seems eclipse can't find `javax.servlet`.  In `cmd`, I'm still able to run `gradle jettyRun`.  Am I missing something? Thanks ahead!

Comment: Did you run `gradle cleanEclipse eclipse` ?

Comment: @david It works!  I did `cleanEclipse` and re-imported the project. Now there is the `servlet-api-2.5.jar` in eclipse.  It seems I installed both the eclipse gradle and cmd gradle. Not sure if that's the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'`

is probably missing in your `build.gradle`. I suppose you have WTP (Web Tools Platform) plugins installed into your Eclipse.

Comment: He should not need that